# MongoDB using range index over hashed index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, hash

Trying to make sense of this mongodb query db.mycollection.find({name:”example”}).explain() where mycollection has both a hashed and a range index on “name”. It shows me that the winningPlan is using the range index and has the hashed index as the rejected plan.

Shouldn’t the hashed index be the preferred way in this case?